# How to use jekyll multiple languages plugin with octopress

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, internationalization, jekyll, octopress

I have trouble getting multiple languages [plugin](https://github.com/screeninteraction/jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin) to work for my octopress blog. I've opened an [issue](https://github.com/screeninteraction/jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin/issues/23) about it, but nobody seems to respond. Does anybody know how to integrate this plugin with octopress?

**Edit**

It generates the posts in the `public/tr` subfolder fine. But the problem is `source/index.html`. Note that I use `{% site.posts %}` variable to iterate over the posts, that is wrong for the `tr` language. What method renders `index.html`, and gives it payload?

Note that it generates the tr language fine in the `public` folder, Only problem is the `index.html`.

Comment: Have you followed the [installation instructions](https://github.com/screeninteraction/jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin#installation) correctly? Assuming [this](https://github.com/eguneys/eguneys.github.io/) is your repo, when I checked the `gh-pages` branch, I found that you haven't *linked* to the correct file in `jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin` repo. Try creating a link to the file at `https://github.com/screeninteraction/jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin/blob/master/lib/jekyll/multiple/languages/plugin.rb`. Or copy the file to your repo.

Comment: @erikroyall Oh I did it, plugin is setup and working, but if you check out my issue, It doesn't pickup the `_posts` in the `tr` folder.

Comment: also see this symlink https://github.com/eguneys/eguneys.github.io/blob/gh-pages/plugins/plugin.rb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugin you are using is not active anymore. I suggest turn to this plugin:

https://github.com/liaohuqiu/jekyll-multiple-languages

The documents:

http://jekyll-langs.liaohuqiu.net/

By the way the document website is built by this plugin.

These are some example websites:

http://cube-sdk.liaohuqiu.net/

http://www.liaohuqiu.net/ , this's my blog, whose source code is also at github: https://github.com/liaohuqiu/liaohuqiu.github.io

I also opened a pull request: https://github.com/eguneys/eguneys.github.io/pull/1, you can check it.

Comment: wouldn't it be better if we could have seperate folders for different languages, for example `tr/index.html` instead of `index.tr.html`.

Comment: only `paginator.posts` works for enumerating the posts for the language, for example `site.posts` doesn't work why?

Comment: There is a `site.posts_by_language`. check here: http://jekyll-langs.liaohuqiu.net/#variables

Comment: There are 2 ways to manger the files. We choose `index.tr.html` instead of `tr/index.html` for making the articles related (only different in language) easy to manager. Anyway, the can get closer :).

Comment: how do i translate `_includes/article.html`? `_includes/article.tr.html` doesn't work.

Comment: The files: `_includes/*` and `_layouts/*` will not be translated. You should render the content by the `page.language`, here is an example: https://github.com/liaohuqiu/liaohuqiu.github.io/blob/463b54779dc902ca4d60727622e20776ba779b03/_layouts/home.html#L9-L13

Comment: How do I use `_layouts` and `_includes` folder for different languages? I should be able to use layouts, can you fix that please? Or is there a mechanism to use variables, like in the previous plugin there is `en.yml` and `tr.yml` that can define variables for use in the templates.

Comment: I had tried before, but failed. You can assign me an issue. I will try it again.